# how to set maxLimit in cakephp pagination

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I am working on cakephp pagination,
I have 150 records in my db
 my requirement is to display display a maximum of 50 records with each page 
 can contain maximum of 5 records,
 I have gone through

```
$this->paginate($myQuery, array('maxLimit' => 50,'limit' => 5 )));
```

and

```
$this->paginate = array('maxLimit' => 50, 'limit' => 5);
```

I am able to limit 5 records per page but not able to limit total records or total no of pages.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maxLimit only limits maximum number of records per page.
You can do something like this

```
$page = $this->request->getQuery('page');
if($page > 5){
     $page = 5;
}

$this->paginate = array(
   // other things
   'page' => $page
);
```